# S3 Bucket Lambda Event- Error: Unable to validate the following destination configurations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, bucket

can someone help me with this problem?

I'm trying to create an event source notification for and S3 bucket in order to process any parquet file in a lambda when it's uploaded in S3, but this error always appears
[image]

In the bucket I'm working on, there are already 16 event notifications, and when I create in other bucket with the same configuration it works. I read that could be policy permissions, but the bucket policy does not deny any role to create event notification.

Can someone help me, please?